# MapKit & iOS 16.4 Issue while rendering polylines

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline, ios16.4

How you guys doing?

So, I have a iOS App, made in Swift.
In this app I have a Map, made with Map Kit and on the iOS 16.4 the polylines don't render correctly.

I have custom Tiles, but I don't think that's the problem because on the above versions it works like a charm.

I have searched fixes and did some, but till now none has worked.
Plus, when my tiles flickering, when I zoom in/out the poly line appears but when it stops flickering it disappears...

I get an error on the console, but the error appears even with out the Polyline created, but I searched a bit and didn't found any relevant

**[VKDefault] Missing DaVinciGroundRenderables for ground mesh layer**

Here's my Polyline rendering:

```
if overlay is MKPolyline {
      let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
      polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange
      polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 7.0
      polylineRenderer.alpha = 1.0
      return polylineRenderer
```

If someone has some hints or have done a fix, I would appreciate some help :)

Thanks & Regards
~Peter

Comment: I have the same problem, without tiles. No problem on physical devices. My workaround: since my app supports iPads, I can run it as "My Mac(designed for iPad)". Here, the polyline rendering works without a physical device. See also https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727521

Comment: @GerdCastan This effects physical devices for me.. being week searching for the problem, but couldn't find yet.

Comment: Same problem in Xcode 15.0 beta: not rendered iniOS simulator, rendered in My Mac (designed for iPad)

Comment: I wrote a small demo app with the intention to write an Apple bug report, and the polyline in the demo app renders fine :-( Am I correct that the metal errors in the log occurs even if the app does not use a polyline? My guess is something else messes up metal and the polyline problem only a symptom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, the problem was because the layers of the Polylines, and so, with the new iOS, the polyline layers was behind the other layers I had, like the tiles. I fixed it by forcing it, to go alway to the top.

A bit of code:

```
  func addOverlayOnTop(_ overlay: MKOverlay) {
    if let last = self.overlays.last {                  // its not the first overlay
      self.insertOverlay(overlay, above: last)        // make sure to add it above all
    } else {                                            // its the first one
      self.addOverlay(overlay)                        // just add it
    }
  }
}

And oh the class that creates the polylien, call this function.
```

Comment: I've been adding the polylines the way you said that solved your problem, but I still have the flickering and messages in the console. 
How do you setup the custom tiles for the map view? Maybe we have a difference there